# OOP JavaScript - Beginner Example

Tags: javascript, oop

I have programmed a bit in `JS`, but found my projects to become really long and unnecessarily complex. I want to learn OOP `JS`, and find it much easier to learn when my code get pictured in colors and figures. Here is a little example program:

```js
var box1Left1 = 0; 
var box1Left2;
var box2Left1 = 0; 
var box2Left2;

setInterval(box1Fly, 10); 
function box1Fly() {
  // Fly Right
  if ( box1Left1 < 300 ) {
    box1Left1++; 
    document.getElementById("box1").style.left = box1Left1 + "px"; 
    box1Left2 = box1Left1;
  }
  // Fly Left
  if ( box1Left1 >= (300) ) {
    box1Left2--; 
    document.getElementById("box1").style.left = box1Left2 + "px"; 
  }
  // Fly Right Again
  if( box1Left2 == 0 ) { box1Left1 = box1Left2; }
  
}

setInterval(box2Fly, 10); 
function box2Fly() {
  // Fly Right
  if ( box2Left1 < 300 ) {
    box2Left1++; 
    document.getElementById("box2").style.left = box2Left1 + "px"; 
    box2Left2 = box2Left1;
  }
  // Fly Left
  if ( box2Left1 >= (300) ) {
    box2Left2--; 
    document.getElementById("box2").style.left = box2Left2 + "px"; 
  }
  // Fly Right Again
  if( box2Left2 == 0 ) { box2Left1 = box2Left2; }
}
```

```html
<div id="box1" style="position:absolute; top: 10px; left: 0px; width: 50px; height: 50px; background-color: #aa39fc;"></div>
  
<div id="box2" style="position:absolute; top: 100px; left: 0px; width: 50px; height: 50px; background-color: #2c79f1;"></div>
```

As you can see, simple things get quite messy! Here is the deal: Can I make only *one* function, some sort of *general* function, that can handle both of these two flying boxes at the same time? Instead of, as now, having two functions ( `box1Fly` & `box2Fly` ) that are almost duplicates?

Thank you very much, Best Regards!

Comment: You should probably post this on [codereview.se].

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> Would feel happier if the downvoter says why the answer is downvoted and more than happy to edit the answer to make it alright. `:)`

Why can't you just pass a parameter, which takes in which `id` should it use? By the way, there's no OO JS in this.

```js
var box1Left1 = 0; 
var box1Left2;
var box2Left1 = 0; 
var box2Left2;

setInterval('boxFly("box1")', 10); 
setInterval('boxFly("box2")', 10);

function boxFly(box_id) {
  // Fly Right
  if ( box1Left1 < 300 ) {
    box1Left1++; 
    document.getElementById(box_id).style.left = box1Left1 + "px"; 
    box1Left2 = box1Left1;
  }
  // Fly Left
  if ( box1Left1 >= (300) ) {
    box1Left2--; 
    document.getElementById(box_id).style.left = box1Left2 + "px"; 
  }
  // Fly Right Again
  if( box1Left2 == 0 ) { box1Left1 = box1Left2; }

}
```

```html
<div id="box1" style="position:absolute; top: 10px; left: 0px; width: 50px; height: 50px; background-color: #aa39fc;"></div>

<div id="box2" style="position:absolute; top: 100px; left: 0px; width: 50px; height: 50px; background-color: #2c79f1;"></div>
```

To convert into **Object Oriented JavaScript**, use this:

```js
var box1Left1 = 0;
var box1Left2;
var box2Left1 = 0;
var box2Left2;

var box = function (id) {
  this.id = id;
  this.fly = function () {
    // Fly Right
    if ( box1Left1 < 300 ) {
      box1Left1++; 
      document.getElementById(id).style.left = box1Left1 + "px"; 
      box1Left2 = box1Left1;
    }
    // Fly Left
    if ( box1Left1 >= (300) ) {
      box1Left2--; 
      document.getElementById(id).style.left = box1Left2 + "px"; 
    }
    // Fly Right Again
    if( box1Left2 === 0 ) { box1Left1 = box1Left2; }
  };
  this.startFlying = function () {
    console.log(id);
    setInterval(this.fly, 10);
  };
};

box1 = new box("box1");
box2 = new box("box2");
box1.startFlying();
box2.startFlying();
```

```html
<div id="box1" style="position:absolute; top: 10px; left: 0px; width: 50px; height: 50px; background-color: #aa39fc;"></div>

<div id="box2" style="position:absolute; top: 100px; left: 0px; width: 50px; height: 50px; background-color: #2c79f1;"></div>
```

Comment: I guess I can, hard though if you don't know how! But now I know, thanks. Ok, so no OO? What is this type of *making-general* stuff then?

Comment: I think the fact there's no OO is exactly what the asker wants to fix, but I could be wrong.

Comment: Welcome @JakeTheSnake! :)

Comment: Why would you keep the coordinate variables out of the objects? This is bad OOP.

Comment: @PraveenKumar There is a `startFlying` function, how would a `stopFlying` function look like? Can you `stop` a function from running?